# How Do I configure PostGIS 2.0 on windows to use ST_GeomFromGeoJSON?

Tags: geojson, postgis-2.0, windows, configuration

I have installed PostGIS 2.0 on a Postgres 9.1 database on a Windows 2012 Server.

I need to write an insert query, which uses [ST_GeomFromGeoJSON()](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromGeoJSON.html). The Docs for this query say that I need - JSON-C >= 0.9, and very helpfully give a link on how to configure PostGIS for that.

Unfortunately, the [article which talks about configuration](http://postgis.org/docs/postgis_installation.html#installation_configuration), only shows how you configure PostGIS on a Linux system.

What steps do I need, to configure PostGIS 2.0 on windows to use ST_GeomFromGeoJSON?

Comment: I have PostGIS 2.0 on Windows and never had a problem with ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(). I didn't even know about JSON-C enablement. What error message do you get if you try to run this SQL command?  SELECT ST_AsText(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-48.23456,20.12345]}')) As wkt;

Comment: I was getting a weird error with `libgeos_c-1.dll` not found; But I installed PostGres+PostGIS on a fresh Virtual Machine and it run without any issue; So I guess it was a system specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

This was a system specific Issue.

I installed PostGres+PostGIS on a fresh Virtual Machine and then ran

```
select ST_Y(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-48.23456,20.12345]}')) As Y;
```

This ran without any issue on the new machine while on the old system it gave an error with `libgeoc_c-1.dll` not found;

So we can conclude that you don't need to do anything special to get this running on Windows. If you Install PostGIS 2.0 from the 'Application Stack Builder' you can use the `ST_GeomFromGeoJSON` without any issues.